# How to show/hide via btn click from parent component?

Tags: lightning-web-components

Show btn is working for this parent to child communication. how to hide the child comp. with same btn??

```
import { LightningElement, track } from "lwc";
export default class ParentComp extends LightningElement {
  @track onClickButtonLabel = "Show";
  startCounter = 0;

  handleStartChange(event) {
    this.startCounter = parseInt(event.target.value);
  }

  handleMaximizeCounter() {
    // const updateCounter = this.template.querySelector('c-child-comp');
    // updateCounter.addToCounter();
    //!we can use this also
    this.template.querySelector("c-child-comp").addToCounter();
    console.log("66");
  }

  handleShowHide(event) {
    const label = event.target.label;
    if (label === "Show") {
      this.onClickButtonLabel = "Hide";
      this.template.querySelector("c-child-comp").showChildCompDetails();
    } else if (label === "Hide") {
      this.onClickButtonLabel = "Show";
    }
  }
}
```

---

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title ='Parent LWC'>
        <lightning-input class= "slds-var-m-around_small" 
                         label="Set Counter" 
                         type="number"
                         min="0" max="10000000" 
                         value={startCounter} 
                         onchange={handleStartChange}>                    
        </lightning-input>

        <lightning-button class = "slds-var-m-around_small"
                          label ={onClickButtonLabel}
                          onclick={handleShowHide}>
        </lightning-button>

        <lightning-button class = "slds-var-m-around_small"
                          label ="ADD 100 TO COUNTER"
                          onclick={handleMaximizeCounter}>
        </lightning-button>

    </lightning-card>

    <!--  calling child comp -->
    <c-child-comp
       counter={startCounter}
    ></c-child-comp>
</template>
```

---

```
import { LightningElement, api } from "lwc";
export default class childComp extends LightningElement {
  
  @api counter=0;
  @api areDetailsVisible=false;

  @api addToCounter(){
    this.counter +=100;
  }

  @api showChildCompDetails(){
      this.areDetailsVisible=true;
  }

}
```

---

```
<template>
  <template if:true={areDetailsVisible}>
  <lightning-card title="Child Comp">
      <p class="slds-var-m-around_small">Counter Value : {counter}</p>
  </lightning-card>
 </template>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set invert the value of flag on child component. In *handleshowHide* function we are checking if label is show then setting it hide else setting it show.
Then calling the child function which is marked as @api and inverting the value that is currently present on it.
If true then would be updated to false and if false then would be updated to true.

```
handleShowHide(event){
    const label = event.target.label;
   if (label === "Show") {
  this.onClickButtonLabel = "Hide";
} else if (label === "Hide") {
  this.onClickButtonLabel = "Show";    
}
```

this.template.querySelector("c-child-comp").showChildCompDetails();

--- Child ---

```
@api showChildCompDetails(){ 
this.areDetailsVisible=!this.areDetailsVisible; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, I prefer markup to JavaScript when I can. I'd simply set a flag in the controller:

```
showChild = false;
buttonLabel = 'Show';
toggleHideShow() {
  this.showChild = !this.showChild;
  this.buttonLabel = this.showChild? 'Hide': 'Show';
}
```

It is generally preferable to actually *hide* the child component when you want to hide it, so don't pass it off to the child, just hide it directly:

```
<c-child-comp if:true={showChild} counter={startCounter}>
```

That said, sometimes you do want to preserve the state, in which case, just pass the parameter in directly:

```
<c-child-comp show={showChild} counter={startCounter}>
```

And in the child component:

```
@api show = false;
```

...

```
<template>
  <template if:true={show}> ... </template>
</template>
```

...

Note that it is illegal for the component to write to any value marked as `@api`, and may break in future code. `@api counter;` should be simply `counter;`.

Also, `@track` is no longer required for simple variables. See my `showChild` example above.

Use public methods (e.g. `showChildCompDetails`) only as necessary. Prefer using data bindings and events whenever possible.